# Referring to myself in my thesis

Tags: thesis

I am not an English native speaker and I wrote my thesis in English. If in the title page of my thesis I would like to write

Advisor: "The name of my advisor"

*M*: "My name",

then what should *M* most commonly be?

My choice for *M* is "student" but am not sure of that.

Note: The common culture of my country makes me write the title page as what I show in my question. I may very well be considered "improper" or even "rude" if I do not do that, and consequently would incur unnecessary judgements.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the word, ["author"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/author).

Comment: Ah, the word had once been my choice. But I were not sure about if the word is suitable. So, assuming that you have noticed "most commonly" in my question, do you mean "author" is the right word?

Comment: Are there any theses in English that have previously been accepted by your institution? If so, look at some of them and follow the same conventions.

Comment: Usually, the format of your title page is dictated by your institution... does your institution not have a required format?

Comment: The three institutions (in the United States) with which I am familiar use "by:".  However, the best answer is to follow your institution's format (jakebeal) if there is one.  Otherwise, use a recently-accepted thesis as an example (Patricia Shanahan.)  See my next comment for why this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I've suggested closing this as "unclear what you're asking."  The definitive answer has to come from the program office of your own institution; none of us can really give you a "right" answer, even though we've tried.

Comment: @BobBrown: The question is about the most commonly used item, not about the correct one, so this is clearly answerable. (Also, at least where I come from, there are institutions that do not make all sorts of regulations on how your thesis should look like.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: You are correct.  I apologize.

Comment: As others have said, the most important step toward answering your question is to check your university's rules. They may be amazingly specific about the format of the title page (as are the rules of my university), and they would override any common culture of your country, any advice we could give you here, and common sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, let me remark that, as other have suggested, it is better to check the preferred format of your university.

In case you can't find any, a possible alternative to *Author* (or nothing) can be *Candidate*, because, at the moment, you are a candidate to some kind of examination and the thesis is the work you have to present before a board of examiners to pass it.

Answer (score 8):

For any specific thesis, you should check the regulations of the institution the thesis will be submitted to. There are often strict rules about the formatting of the title page.

I've not come across the advisor being listed first. The format I'm most familiar with would be something like the following:

> ## Why there are no Frogs on the Moon
>
> ### Neil Armstrong
>
> Advisor: [Dr Thomas O. Paine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_O._Paine)

There's no need to write a word before the author's name. It is understood that any title page will contain the title and the author so any name that is not explained as being something else (e.g., "Advisor:", "Editor:") must be the author. You see the same with academic papers: the authors are usually not explicitly described as authors; it's just implicit that the list of names below the title is the list of authors.

Note also that the name(s) of the author(s) usually come before any other people who have contributed to the document. Authorship is regarded as by far the most important contribution.

Comment: Appreciating your support! There is something that I have to say. The common culture of my country makes me write the title page as what I show in my question. I may very well be considered "improper" or even "rude" if I do not do that, and consequently would incur unnecessary judgements. But I still appreciate your help. I guess cultural difference takes place and I will ponder over this point much more.

Comment: That is a national complex, though I hate that.

Comment: @Chou OK. I wasn't aware that there were places that did it differently -- I guess you weren't either! You should edit your question to include this information, as it's rather important. Perhaps you could also include the form of words that is used in your native language.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write (**By:"Your name"**), that's it.